# Anchor incorrectly sending to bottom of page

Tags: html, anchor

I have the following code on my local page...

```
<h2 id="SomeAnchor">Some Anchor</h2>
```

And when I go to `localhost:3000/#SomeAnchor`, the page loads at the very bottom (large page). I achieved the exact same when using `<a name="SomeAnchor></a>` as well. Header is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which would imply HTML5 afaik.

Trying to understand why it is directing the browser to the bottom of the page, and how to fix that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your anchor at the bottom of the page?

Comment: No, it is fairly close to the top of the page. There are at least 3 full page views worth of information below it, yet `localhost:3000/#SomeAnchor` always directs to the bottom.

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers? If so, I think it might be caused by JS script, yet it's difficult to judge. Would you mind providing us a fiddle? If it's not possible, do you use any plugins or any scripts that play around with hash in the url?

Comment: I didn't consider using any other browsers -- it seems to work in IE, but not in Chrome. That gives me somewhere to investigate -- thank you.